# How many descriptors can be retrieved in one request using the descriptor digest?

Tags: protocol, directory

in the Tor [dir-spec.txt](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/dir-spec.txt) I can see a note stating that due to squid proxy url limitations it is only possible to download 96 descriptors when using the fingerprints.

Does this also apply to the digests? Or is it an other value for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the digest of the descriptor is done the same way the fingerprint is calculated both have a binary length of 20 bytes (40 bytes in hex notation).

So the same limit applies for the descriptor digest.